# "Error: Unable to find git in your PATH" en Visual Code

Tags: git, windows

Hola estoy empezando a aprender Flutter, pero tengo un problema que no me deja avanzar en el aprendizaje de este mismo, he instalado flutter siguiendo las instrucciones de la documentación, y he creado una aplicacion siguiendo los pasos indicados. Si ejecuto flutter doctor desde CMD no me marca ningun error[image: Flutter Doctor desde CMD]

Pero si trato de ejecutarlo desde Visual Studio Code me marca el siguiente error:

[image: Flutter Doctor desde Visual]

Ya he seguidos los pasos de varios tutoriales para intentar resolverlo, pero ninguno da solución al problemaa, adjunto evidencia de las variables de entorno y los comandos que he realizado.
[image: Variables De Entorno]
[image: Variables de Entorno]
[image: Variables De Entorno]

Tambien he ejecutado algunos comandos que encontre en una publicacion similar a esta pero no pudieron resolver el problema

[image: Comandos]

Y si Ejecuto el comando de Flutter Devices desde la paleta de comandos de Visual no encuentra ningun dispositivo, pero si lo ejecuto desde CMD si funciona, no se a que se deban estos errores, si me falta alguna configuracion,espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví reinstalando flutter y ejecutando el comando

```
git config --global --add safe.directory '*'
```